# Python 'for x in list_of_xes' iterates over same item twice

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, celery

I have the following code:

```
@app.task()
def add_data_bulk(source_uuid, bulkdata):
    print(type(bulkdata))
    print(type(bulkdata[1]))
    print(len(bulkdata))
    for datum in bulkdata:
        print("Datum {}: source_uuid: {}, timestamp: {}".format(bulkdata.index(datum), source_uuid, datum["timestamp"]))
        new_datum = data.Datum(source_uuid, datum["sensor_type"], datum["timestamp"], datum["value"])
        session = db_setup.get_db_session()
        session.add(new_datum)
        session.commit()
    return None
```

Bulkdata is a list of dicts (it's a JSON array of objects).
The for loop iterates through the same item twice. Can anyone tell me why that is? The print statement in the loop gives me:

```
[2018-04-19 16:09:28,847: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] Datum 0: source_uuid: 30, timestamp: 1524146968.8267977
[2018-04-19 16:09:28,856: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] Datum 0: source_uuid: 30, timestamp: 1524146968.8267977
```

Comment: Does it do that for every item or just one specific? Are you sure that this is not already present in your `bulkdata`?

Comment: are you sure entries are not duplicate inside bulkdata? The use of `bulkdata.index(datum) ` doesn't guarantee uniqueness because it will always find the first...

Comment: @Graipher it does that for the first Item and then fails because of a unique constraint in my DB

Comment: I will print out the first two elements of the list to check if they are the same @MarcoPantaleoni, one sec

Comment: You were correct, the items in bulkdata were equal. I was confused by the index statement giving back the same index twice. Thank you both!